# NaCl helper process running without a sandbox! error when running npm tests

Tags: google-chrome, docker, npm

I'n having a problem when running some npm test. The error I'm receiving is: "NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!", which is true, as I'm running the browser with the "--no-sandbox" option. I have to run this option due to the fact that the browser runs as root, and I don't have an option to run it a different user at all(it's a docker image).
Can anyone please help me to sort it out?

P.S I'm installing the browser in the following way:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

This error message...

```
NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

...implies that *you have no setuid sandbox* in your system, hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be, if you want to run Chrome and only use the namespace sandbox, you can set the flag:

```
--disable-setuid-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the setuid sandbox (Linux only). But if you do so on a host without appropriate kernel support for the namespace sandbox, Chrome will not spin up. As an alternative you can also use the flag:

```
--no-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed.

Example:

```
chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']
},
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Security Considerations - ChromeDriver - Webdriver for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101367/security-considerations-chromedriver-webdriver-for-chrome/60111052#60111052)

---

### Deep dive

As per the documentation in [Linux SUID Sandbox Development](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) needs a `SUID` helper binary to turn on the sandbox on Linux. In majority of the cases you can install the proper sandbox for you using the command:

```
build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
```

This program will install the proper *sandbox* for you in `/usr/local/sbin` and tell you to update your `.bashrc` if required.

However, there can be some exceptions as an example, if your `setuid` binary is out of date, you will get messages such as:

```
Running without the SUID sandbox!
```

Or

```
The setuid sandbox provides API version X, but you need Y
You are using a wrong version of the setuid binary!
```

In these cases, you need to:

- Build `chrome_sandbox` whenever you build chrome (`ninja -C xxx chrome chrome_sandbox` instead of `ninja -C xxx chrome`)
- After building, execute `update-linux-sandbox.sh`.

  ```
  # needed if you build on NFS!
  sudo cp out/Debug/chrome_sandbox /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```
- Finally, you have to include the following line in your `~/.bashrc` (or `.zshenv`):

  ```
  export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```

Comment: Where can I will get this update-linux-sandbox.sh? Also I am not using docar

Comment: @dpkrai96 got it from here https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/b05c228f0b14/build/update-linux-sandbox.sh

But how do I build the .sh file? I ran the command `build/update-linux-sandbox.sh`  but it's showing: `# build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
-bash: build/update-linux-sandbox.sh: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using karma to run your tests, make sure you are using `ChromeHeadless` as the browser on `karma.conf.js`